# SQL: add a default constraint on foreign key column where foreign key reference does not exist

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, default

What will happen if we try to add a default value constraint on a foreign key where that default value does not exist in the table ?

Example:

- `Table_Person` has `Gender` column as foreign key
- `Table_Gender` has rows with values '1' and '2'

What will happen if I make default constraint in `Table_Person` for `Gender` column with default value = '3' ?

Will it be created or throw an error? And reason for that?

Comment: If the parent table only has the keys for 1 and 2, then trying to create a row with value 3 in the child table won't work. That's the whole point of an FK constraint. You can only add rows with null, 1, or 2 in the child table. Or... you can drop the FK constraint altogether and forget about data integrity :)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? WHat happened when you created those tables/constraints?

Answer (score 0):

It will depend **highly** on what concrete database system (RDBMS) you're using.

For **SQL Server**:

- You *can* create both tables, including the default constraint in `Table_Person`
- You *can* insert rows into `Table_Person` that explicitly define a value for `Gender` which is 1 or 2
- You **can not however** insert rows into `Table_Person` that omit the value for `Gender` and thus would get the default value of 3 inserted - since that violates the FK constraint